Modelling auto parts equivalency in a database
I am developing an auto parts quoting and pricing application for a company that sells auto parts. The client wants the application to handle their internal daily operations, such as calculating parts prices and creating, and managing quotes. To support these requirements, I have designed a database with more than 20 tables.
The client wants the application to address a common issue in the auto spare parts industry: parts equivalency. Equivalent parts are parts that can be used interchangeably. For example, if a part with part number (a unique identifier for auto parts across the industry) PN0001 is equivalent to parts with part numbers PN0002, PN0003, and PN0004, then all these parts can replace one another.
Tables in my database include parts, vehicles, manufacturers, parts_equivalence, and vehicle_parts_compatibility:
database design for parts quoting and pricing application
To capture the equivalence information, I created a table that is a self-join of the parts table, with part_id and equivalent_part_id which looks like this:
parts_equivalence table example content
PN0001 is equivalent to every part in this table. But if I want to see if PN0001 is equivalent to PN0010, I have to loop through every record: if PN0001 = PN0002 and PN0002 = PN0003 then PN0001 = PN0003.
That is not the way to do this as we are going to miss a lot of things.
How do I model this concept effectively in a database?

I would try to store this data without any attempts to save a space.Lets assume three parts PN_1, PN_2, PN_3. They are equivalent to each other. So we store PN_1->PN_2,PN_1->PN_3,PN_2->PN_3,PN_2->PN_1, PN_3->PN_1,PN_3->PN_2.

I am surprised to see a table describing all parts' attributes such as length and width and then another table that mainly points at two parts rows and says they are identical. Wouldn't they have to have the same measures when they are identical? And if that is so, why store the data redundantly? I'd rather expect one table describing the part with its measures and another table listing all the names the part is called.

The comp sci jargon for your required result is “transitive closure of the equivalency relationship”. Maybe that can help you find a solution?

This question is similar to: How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
